# Footer loads in middle then sticks to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, loading, footer

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. Whenever I refresh or open the page new, the footer loads right in the middle before quickly being pushed back to the bottom. It is incredibly annoying and I have tried numerous method.

If anyone has a suggestion, please let me know.

I'm still a newbie!

Thank you, 
R

Comment: Code code code! We cannot know what you're trying unless you show us

Comment: By the sounds of it your footer renders before your main content

Comment: Also give a link to a jsfiddle

Comment: So what you do it. Get a cow, wash it really clean and walk it to the nearest shop. Get it some chocolate, ride it down the motorway screaming "**Yippy, I'm a farmer**" and that should solve the problem. Alternatively you could show us some code and we could explain where you went wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your DOM sets the footer in the middle of the screen and after the DOM is loaded some javascript code sets its position to the bottom.